# Eclipse compare editor: syntax highlighting for files without proper extension

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

my current (Lua-)project contains multiple files without a proper file extension (due to historical reasons). By choosing 'Open with' one can set a proper editor to get syntax highlighting.

But it seems that this decision has no impact on the compare editor:

If I compare two files with a proper file extension, syntax highlighting is enabled (in this case I have also the possibility to switch between 'Default Compare', 'Lua Source File Compare' and 'Text Compare').
But if I compare two files without extension, I just get a 'Text Compare'.

Is it possible (and if so, how) to enable syntax highlighting for files without extension within the compare mode in Eclipse?

Comment: You better to provide more details.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram: what do you think is missing/what is not clear enough?

Comment: Here I meant, your default syntax highlighting in Eclipse etc.

Comment: Compare is probably just using the file content type configured in the Preferences in 'General > Content Types'. I don't think there is any way to configure a content type for all files with no extension, you can configure individual file names though.

Comment: @greg-449 i had hoped to avoid this step but it seems to be only way